# False proof that $1-1+1-1+1\cdots= \frac12$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fake-proofs

The expression $1+\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\cdots$ is equal to $\dfrac{x}{x-1}$ when $|x|>1$ by using the formula for geometric series. But the limit as $x\rightarrow-1$ of the expression is equal to $\frac12$ (this can be clearly seen on a graph). However the limit as $x\rightarrow-1$ of the expression is also equal to $1-1+1-1+1+\cdots$, so therefore $1-1+1-1+1\cdots=\dfrac{1}{2}$?

I feel as though I messed up my limits somewhere, can someone help me please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series

Comment: note that the formula $\frac{x}{x-1}$ works for $|x|>1$

Comment: Hint: you've assumed $\sum_{n\ge0}\lim_{x\to(-1)^+}x^{-n}=\lim_{x\to(-1)^+}\sum_{n\ge0}x^{-n}$.

Comment: You could also just call the series $S$ and then note that $1-S=S$ which gives you $S=\frac 12$.  But, of course, there are other simple looking ways to sum the series that give different results.  Such as $S=(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots =0+0+\cdots=0$.

Comment: @J.G. I can sort of see what you're getting at. Then is it not true in general that you can break the limit of (a+b) into the limit of (a) + the limit of (b)?

Comment: Kelvin, we do have $\lim_n(a_n+b_n)=\lim_na_n+\lim_nb_n$ when both limits on the right hand side exist. It's rather the fact that there are infinitely many terms (as opposed to such two, $a$ and $b$) that ruins it.

Comment: The limit actually *does* converge to $1/2$ in some sense if you take the average of the partial sums

Comment: I said take the average of the partial sums @AlvinL.

Comment: The sum $S=1-1+1-1…$ is not well-defined. As a series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n=\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n $ simply does not converge, as the limit I wrote does not exist. You can see that the formal infinite sum is not well-defined because you can rearrange terms to get different results (e.g., since there are an infinite number of $1$ and $-1$ , you can also rewrite it as $S=(1+1-1)+(1+1-1)+(1+1-1)+\dots=1+1+1+\dots=\infty$; you can do the same and obtain $-\infty$. Thus, rearranging the order of the summands, you get something different).

Comment: What you wrote simply proves that the identity $1+1/x+1/x^2+\dots=x/(x-1)$ does not hold in general (or it doesn’t make sense) for $|x|\leq 1$. There is no contradiction.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see now, although it is still quite strange to me that this rule breaks down when there are infinitely many terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain, why your approach does not work: We have for $|x|>1$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty1/x^n=\frac{x}{x-1}$, it is absolutely correct that the limit *from the left*: $\lim_{x\to -1^{-}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty1/x^n=1/2$, but this does not mean that $1-1+1-1+\cdots$ converges to $1/2$ because you can not naively interchange sum and limit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still puzzles me why you can't interchange the sum and limit. To my understanding, you can do it for a finite number of terms. So why not an infinite number?

Comment: This that hold for finite number do not necessarily hold for infinite series. Because an infinite series is the **limit** of finite partial sums, what holds for the partial sums may not always be passed on to the limit.

Comment: Wait, upon rereading I do not understand your point @HansLundmark. I do mean the limit from below. Since then $|x|>1$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int_{0}^{1}xdx = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}xdx = \int_{0}^{1}e^{\ln(x)}dx $$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^{n}(x)}{n!}dx = \sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} \int_{0}^{1} \ln^{n}(x)dx $$
$$\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}n!}{n!} = \sum_{0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}$$
This does not mean that this series is equal $\frac{1}{2}$. This mean that the result of this development is a divergent series. So, for some pre-defined scopes, some divergent series could have some values. If and only if you specify the value and scope in logic terms.